# Origin/meaning of "burninate"

Tags: etymology, internet

I've seen the word "burninate" used around the internet a bit, most recently in this [MetaSO answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108231/the-net-tag-is-used-for-different-purposes/108449#108449). The basic meaning of it seems fairly clear, but where did this come from? An online dictionary searched yielded no results, as did etymonline. A wikipedia search redirected to an article, but searching the document only found the word where it indicated the search had redirected to that page, and no other mentions of it in the article.

Can someone please explain where this word came from?

Comment: Something that someone with cystitis does?

Comment: How might Ceiling Cat use this word?  "Can I haz my cheezeburger burninated, pleeze?"  ;-D

Comment: It's what you must do to the countryside, peasants, and thatch-roofed cottages. Isn't it obvious? :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It came from the [classic Homestar Runner cartoon](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7gz1DIIxmEE) in an episode where Strong Bad creates a character called [Trogdor the Burninator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Bad#Trogdor_the_Burninator).

Comment: Turns out there's also a [transcript of this episode](http://www.hrwiki.org/wiki/dragon).

Comment: Consummate V's!

Comment: It would be great if you could incorporate the meaning it has especially within the stackexchange network. After all the question asks for origin and meaning. ;)